# Fix invalid nested lists with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been left with a rather large legacy pile of HTML. I have multiple lists that have sub lists that have not been incorporated into list item, although this renders correctly, it still causes a problem in accessibility testing. Is there a jQuery method that allow me to correct this, until I can convince the content providers to do it properly?

```
<ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
       <ul class="shouldBeSublist">
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
      </ul>
    <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

last failed attempt...

```
$("ul ul").append(function () {
                return this.closest("li");
});
```

wanted outcome...

```
<ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list
       <ul class="shouldBeSublist">
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
      </ul>
    **</li>**
    <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only lists which are children of lists and use jQuery's `appendTo()` method to move them to the previous list element:

```
$('ul > ul').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('li'));
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/appendto/

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8xjn6240/)

Comment: Revised to use more explicit selectors. This may prevent inappropriate changes.